# Function system in C++ not working correctly or i do not correctly compile with MinGW, help me

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

**I have a C++ code (main.cpp)**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main ()
{
  system("cd %appdata% & mkdir test");
  system("Pause");
}
```

I compile using MinGW :

```
"mingw32-g++.exe" main.cpp -o main.exe
```

When I run main.exe it make a diriectory in current directory, not the expected `%appdata%` directory.

However, when I compile using Code::Blocks, it is working correctly (it makes a directory in %appdata%)

**How can I compile (with command line in Windows, not using Code::Blocks) and have the program work as I expect ?**

Comment: Read your question one more time and try to make sense of it.

Comment: Add this line to the start of main: `system("echo %appdata%");` to verify where the directory is being created. Also try it at the command line before you run main.exe to make sure it is defined correctly.

Comment: Somewhere code::blocks will provide the command line it is using to invoke g++ if for no other reason than debugging the IDE's build tools dialogues. Find the command line and duplicate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that in the MinGW case, you are executing the program from a different drive than the one that contains `%AppData%` (almost always C:), and in the Code::Blocks case, you are executing from the same drive as `%AppData%`. One way to ensure that you're always on the correct drive is to add `/d` to the `cd` command:

```
system("cd /d %appdata% & mkdir test");
```

From `cd /?`:

> Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current
>   directory for a drive.